# Cloudant Search Index Analyzers doesn't sort alphabetically

Tags: cloudant

I have tested all available Analyzers on my Search Index. But none, except Keyword Analyzer, gave me proper sorted results in alphabetical order. But Keyword Analyzer doesn't fit in my filtering requirements. With Keyword Analyzer i couldn't search for a sub-string in a given sentence. 
Example: "description": "This is 2 test different Analyzers in a Search Index"
Whitespace Analyzer gives proper search results but it doesn't help me with sorting. Does anyone have pointers on how we can achieve both sorting and searching with Search Index?

Answer (score 0):

The analyzers define how text is broken into words and how those words are truncated (stemmed) into tokens for indexing. For example, the keyword analyzer keeps words intact in their entirety which is handy for tags.

Analyzers don't have much to do with sorting. By default, sorting is by "best match first" i.e. the documents that are the closest match to your input string appear first, which is what you might expect from a search engine.

You can override the default sort by supplying a `sort` parameter. e.g.

```
e.g. q=frank+sinatra&sort=date
```

See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search for further sorting options.

Comment: Mycriteria is to sort by fields. Suppose i have a field called description with long sentences, sorting on description sort=description is not giving alphabetical sort. It is using some algorithm based on the Analyzer we use. But, I want to sort any field alphabetically.

Comment: Mycriteria is to sort by fields. Suppose i have a field called description with long sentences, sorting on description sort=description is not giving alphabetical sort. It is using some algorithm based on the Analyzer we use. But, I want to sort any field alphabetically.
Do you know how to sort alphabetically on a given field?